# Noether's theorem: Transformation is a symmetry if the Lagrangian changes by a total derivative

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem

While reading a lecture note, I am quite stuck on the very first part of proving Noether's theorem.
As a setup, they defined the transformation
$\delta \phi_a(x) = X_a(\phi)$
is a symmetry if the Lagrangian changes by a total derivative,
$\delta L = \partial_\mu F^\mu$
for some set of functions $F^\mu(\phi)$.

Here, I don't quite see the connection between the transformation being a symmetry and Lagrangian changing by a total derivative. Could someone please explain how those two conditions are connected in a more intuitive sense?

Answer (score 2):

A transformation is a symmetry if it leaves the *action* $S$ invariant (not the Lagrangian).
Since
$$
S = \int \! d^4 x \, \mathcal{L},
$$
if $\mathcal{L}$ changes by a total derivative, you can use the $d=4$ equivalent of Gauss' theorem to produce a surface term which we say goes to 0 at the boundary of space-time.
this is not obvious though and there do exist theories where this surface term can cause you issues, but in general we assume that once you integrate over the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$, it disappears.

Comment: Some additional explanations : the equations of motion are given by $\delta S = 0$. Therefore, a transformation that changes the lagrangian only by a total derivative will preserve the equations of motion : it is a symmetry of the system.

Answer (score -1):

Such a transformation is a symmetry of the action but not of the Lagrangian. It leaves the equations of motion invariant but does not correspond to a Noether conserved current.

Comment: It does have an associated Noether current, namely $$j^{\mu} = \delta\phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi_a)} - F^\mu$$

Comment: @solublefish How is this a conserved Noether current?

Comment: The variation of the Lagrangian is $$\delta \mathcal L =  \delta\phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \phi_a} +  \partial_\mu\delta\phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial ( \partial_\mu \phi_a)}$$ When the Euler-Lagrange are satisfied, you have : $$\delta \mathcal L = \delta\phi_a   \partial_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (  \partial_\mu \phi_a)} +  \partial_\mu\delta\phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial ( \partial_\mu \phi_a)} = \partial_\mu \left (\delta\phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial ( \partial_\mu \phi_a)}\right)$$

Comment: Therefore, when $\delta \mathcal L = \partial_\mu F^\mu$, you see that $$j^\mu = \delta \phi_a \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu \phi_a)} - F^\mu$$ is a conserved current.

Comment: @SolubleFish This is not a comment but a different answer.

Comment: This not an answer to the OP's question, which was about the interpretation of the transformation as a symmetry. I am answering your question from [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/632834/noethers-theorem-transformation-is-a-symmetry-if-the-lagrangian-changes-by-a-t/632841?noredirect=1#comment1426958_632841)

Comment: @SolubleFish Do you have a practical example of this? I tend to believe that $\delta L= \partial_\mu F^\mu$ implies that $\partial_\mu F^\mu=0$. If so, the conserved current that you write down is just the sum of two independently conserved currents, which is trivially conserved.

Comment: Under a translation by $\epsilon^\mu$, the variation of the Lagrangian is $\delta \mathcal L = \epsilon^\mu \partial_\mu \mathcal L = \partial_\mu \left( \epsilon^\mu\mathcal L\right) \neq 0$.

Comment: @SolubleFish In such a case the system exchanges energy-momentum with some outside degrees of freedom that are not included in the hamiltonian. It is counterintuitive to call this expression a conserved Noether current.

Comment: It seems intuitive enough for me, since it is indeed conserved. This is what D.Tong does in his QFT course for example (see [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf))

Comment: This is like saying there is no leak since the total amount of water inside your boat and in the sea is constant. It's a free country though.